# How to print the title of the different columns and lines of a matrix?

Tags: java, arrays

So i have this assignment of doing a little table of points for a tournament, pretty easy, but I want it to be

```
                        Dom 1       Dom 2   Dom 3        Dom 4
Mario Mort y Chepita     45          22      50           30
Chunche y Lichita        55          49      66           60 
Porcionsón y Mary        40          38      47           70    
Maikol Jordan y Paty     65          70      70           65
```

And I cant seem to be able to put the "titles" (Dom 1, Dom 2, Mario Mort y Chepita, Chunche y Lichita, etc etc)

> ```
> public static void puntajeTorneo() {
> ```

```
    //Primer equipo
    puntajes[0][0] = 45;
    puntajes[0][1] = 22;
    puntajes[0][2] = 50;
    puntajes[0][3] = 30;
    //Segundo equipo
    puntajes[1][0] = 55;
    puntajes[1][1] = 49;
    puntajes[1][2] = 66;
    puntajes[1][3] = 60;
    //Tercer equipo
    puntajes[2][0] = 40;
    puntajes[2][1] = 38;
    puntajes[2][2] = 47;
    puntajes[2][3] = 70;
    //Cuarto equipo
    puntajes[3][0] = 65;
    puntajes[3][1] = 70;
    puntajes[3][2] = 70;
    puntajes[3][3] = 65;
}//Fin inicio de matriz PuntajeTorneo.

public static void totales() {

    int total1 = puntajes[0][0] + puntajes[0][1] + puntajes[0][2] + puntajes[0][3];
    int total2 = puntajes[1][0] + puntajes[1][1] + puntajes[1][2] + puntajes[1][3];
    int total3 = puntajes[2][0] + puntajes[2][1] + puntajes[2][2] + puntajes[2][3];
    int total4 = puntajes[3][0] + puntajes[3][1] + puntajes[3][2] + puntajes[3][3];

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Primer equipo: " + total1 + "\nSegundo equipo: " + total2 + "\nTercer equipo: " + total3 + "\nCuarto equipo: " + total4);
}//Fin totales. 

public static void imprimePuntajes() {
    for (int x = 0; x < puntajes.length; x++) {

        for (int y = 0; y < puntajes[x].length; y++) {

            System.out.print(puntajes[x][y] + "     ");

        }

        System.out.println();

    }
}//Fin Imprime Puntaje
```

This only prints

45     22     50     30
55     49     66     60
40     38     47     70
65     70     70     65

But I need to have titles per columns and lines.

Comment: What are X, C, V and B

Comment: Yeah, sorry I printed it wrong, It has an extra part on the beginning explaining it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two arrays of strings:

```
String[] columnTitles = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
```

and another one for `rowTitles`.

Then use another loop to print out the columnTitles before you print your matrix.

When you print a matrix row you can print the appropriate `rowTitle` before you print the first element of the row.

Comment: Like this?                                                                                                   `public static void imprimePuntajes() {
          for (int i = 0; i < puntajes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(columnas[i]);

            for (int x = 0; x < puntajes.length; x++) {
                System.out.println(filas[x]);
                for (int y = 0; y < puntajes[x].length; y++) {
                    System.out.print(puntajes[x][y] + "     ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Sorry if it looks too messy, second time using this site.

Comment: Its not working, it prints the same matrix 4 times with the columns and rows before every matrix.

Comment: Its printing that 4 times, changing dom1 to dom2, dom3...                                                                                                      
                                                                                                      
Dom1
Primer equipo
45     22     50     30     
Segundo equipo
55     49     66     60     
Tercer equipo
40     38     47     70     
Cuarto equipo
65     70     70     65

Comment: Your first loop should just print the column headings -- it doesn't need to print the whole matrix for each column.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest and less change to your implementation to add headers.
try as following

```
  public class Test {

    private static int[][] puntajes = new int[4][4];
    private static String[] hearders = new String[4];

    public static void main(String[] args){
      puntajeTorneo();
      imprimePuntajes();
    }

    public static void puntajeTorneo() {

      //Primer equipo
      hearders[0] = "Dom 1 \t\t\t\t";
      hearders[1] = "Dom 2  \t\t\t\t";
      hearders[2] = "Mario Mort y Chepita";
      hearders[3] = "Chunche y Lichita   ";

      puntajes[0][0] = 45;
      puntajes[0][1] = 22;
      puntajes[0][2] = 50;
      puntajes[0][3] = 30;
      //Segundo equipo
      puntajes[1][0] = 55;
      puntajes[1][1] = 49;
      puntajes[1][2] = 66;
      puntajes[1][3] = 60;
      //Tercer equipo
      puntajes[2][0] = 40;
      puntajes[2][1] = 38;
      puntajes[2][2] = 47;
      puntajes[2][3] = 70;
      //Cuarto equipo
      puntajes[3][0] = 65;
      puntajes[3][1] = 70;
      puntajes[3][2] = 70;
      puntajes[3][3] = 65;
    }//Fin inicio de matriz PuntajeTorneo.

    public static void imprimePuntajes() {
      for(int a = 0; a<hearders.length; a++){
        System.out.print(hearders[a] + "\t");
      }
      System.out.println();
      for (int x = 0; x < puntajes.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < puntajes[x].length; y++) {
          System.out.print(puntajes[x][y] + "\t\t\t\t\t\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
    }//Fin Imprime Puntaje
  }
```